# Examples of a uniformly convergent sequence of functions with the given property

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence

I am trying to find a sequence $(f_n)$ of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, but $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_n(x)\ne\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x).$$
Please help.

Comment: If you find a solution of the first problem, it will solve the second problem as well. Anyway, what are your attempts to solve it? I suggest you to start by looking for functions $f_n$ uniformly converging to $0$, but satisfying $\int f_n = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Yeah! Uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence.

Comment: Try with $f_n(x)=\cases{1/n & $0<x<n$ \\ 0 & otherwise}$ and then make it continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$, where
$$f_n(x):=\begin{cases}
1/n &\mbox{if $|x|\leq n$}\\
\frac{(n+1)-|x|}{n} &\mbox{if $n\leq |x|\leq n+1$}\\
0   &\mbox{if $|x|\geq n+1$}.\\
\end{cases}$$
which converges to $0$ uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_n(x)\,dx\ge 2>0=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\, dx.$$

Answer (score 2):

The sequence defined as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1/n, & \mbox{if } n\mbox{ 0 $\le x \le n$ } \\ 0, & \mbox{if } \mbox{$x>n $ and $x<0$} \end{cases}$$

Is not a sequence of continous function but has the property

$$1=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_n(x)\ne\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)=0$$

A little change of this sequence gives you what you want.